# How can I translate my jquery to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, translation, translate

I have

```
$('#hidden-data').find('#' + $(this).attr('id')).html(currdata);
var hiddata = $('#hidden-data').find('#' + $(this).attr('id')).html();
```

I want to translate this to javascript but my brain is melted. 
Please help ;p

Comment: Isn't `$('#hidden-data').find('#' + $(this).attr('id'))` the same as `$('#hidden-data')`?

Comment: @Josh - `this` doesn't refer to `hidden-data` in that context. Or rather...it may or may not.

Comment: It filters the DOM to the attr id within the scope of hidden-data, thanks

Comment: That's another problem then, IDs aren't valid unless they're unique, do you have the same ID repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var o = document.getElementById(thisid);
o.innerHTML = currdata;
var hiddata = o.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest version, given that IDs should be unique:

```
var hiddata = this.innerHTML = currdata;
```

The shortened jQuery version accounting for ID uniqueness makes this a bit more apparent:

```
$(this).html(currdata);
var hiddata = $(this).html();
```

Since you're taking the `id` attribute from `this` and no *other* element should have that ID, just use `this`, no need to find anything else in the DOM...you should already have the element.